# Marker transform(translate) doesn't work

Tags: highcharts

I need to translate the marker symbols by some pixels such that it doesn't overlap with the series line. But nothing seems working. Any suggestion?

Code:

```
 $(function () {
   $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    series: [{
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)',

        },
        data: [{
            y: 10,
        }, {
            y: 25,
        }, {
            y: 12,
        }, {
            y: 31
        }]
    }]
},function(chart){

    $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,point){


        this.graphic.attr({
            transform: "translate(-13,0)"
        });

    });

  });
});
```

Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yd8hV/13/

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap your $.each() function into setTimeout() function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
            $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (i, point) {
                this.graphic.attr({
                    transform: "translate(-15,-35)"
                });
            });
        }, 50);
```

You need to do it because translate options are modified later than your callback function.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/yd8hV/20/